# Pycharms debugger interactive console very slow

Tags: python, debugging, ide, pycharm

I just started trying out PyCharm, and while it is very nice, I found the interactive console in debugger (that can be activated with "Show Python Prompt" on a breakpoint) is unusably slow. If I keep pressing enter, for example, after 2-3 tries, I have to wait several seconds for the next prompt to show up.

Is this a common experience? I'm running Pycharm with a pretty fast machine (with i7-3770 CPU) so I was wondering if something is wrong.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue, and this is with version 2017

Comment: I'm into this to. Do you run pycharm on windows?

Comment: Yes I run pycharm on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I too have experienced the same problem quite a few times but With every new version released new problem too pop out . Its not the first time PyCharm is giving some one a hard time. In previous version the IDE would just stop working or not debug at all .

The best way to solve this is by writing to Jet Brains so they can find and solve the issue and release a new update.

Comment: Any new idea, what to do?